# Regex for 301 Redirects to shorten permalink URLs in Wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am new to regex, so this might be an overly simple question.

I have a Wordpress site using permalinks that has about 1000 posts with URLs that are using this general format:

`http://webdomain.com/123456/name-of-a-post/`

I would like to create a redirect rule that will point the incoming traffic to this permalink scenario:

`http://webdomain.com/name-of-a-post/`

Essentially, I want to shorten the URL to remove the post ID.

Is this something that regex would be appropriate for? If so, which regex would work?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```regex
(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/[0-9]{6}(\/\S*)
```

**Replace With:** `$1$2`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- Will find urls with six digit id's
- Allow you to remove the id substring

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/sY0xQ1/1

**Sample text**

```
http://webdomain.com/123456/name-of-a-post/
```

**After Replacment**

```
http://webdomain.com/name-of-a-post/
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                     'http'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                       's' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\/]+                   any character except: '\/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{6}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (6 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```